# Can't link a bar button to an @IBAction in superclass

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uistoryboard, ibaction

I have a number of view controllers, each with their own menu button (a `UIBarButton`, added in the storyboard). Now I want to link all these up to a single `@IBAction` function in their superclass (the superclass is the same for all the view controllers with that menubutton).

Now I have linked up `@IBOutlet`s to a superclass before, but it doesn't seem to work with `@IBAction`s, even though the function isn't private, and it definitely is part of the superclass (I am refactoring, previously it was an `@IBAction` in each class, which only did `menuButtonTap()` (calling the method in the superclass).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem by manually creating an `@IBAction` on the superclass, and giving them the same name as the ones I create in the subclasses. Then I deleted the ones in the subclasses. This leaves a 'dangling reference' from the storyboard, according to Xcode, but I know it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Although this still does not work as of Xcode 9.4 for general purpose `UIViewController` (but your workaround still does work ), please note that it works as expected for `UITableViewCell` templates in storyboard.

If some of your template cells in storyboard share the same base class containing `@IBOutlet` properties, you will be able to link them to every template cell instance as you usually do:

[image: Link @IBOutlet from parent class to storyboard prototype cell component]

Then Xcode will show a popup for telling in which prototype cell the link is "backed":

[image: Select "backing" prototype cell]

I'm not sure why this second step is necessary though, since you designate a specific component from **within** a given prototype cell

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like you do when adding an action to a UITabbar button from subview class.

Assuming btn is a UIBarButtonItem,

```
[btn setTarget:self.superview];

[btn setAction:@selector(menuButtonTap:)]
```

Comment: This is a solution, but I have the items in storyboard, and not in my classes. In my solution, I only add one `@IBAction` to the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using __unused keyword by any chance? If you do the IBAction won't show up in storyboard(I am using Xcode 6.3.2)

```
- (IBAction)actionBack:(__unused id)sender;
vs
- (IBAction)actionBack:(id)sender;
```

To make it show up and selectable removed the __unsused keyword.

Comment: Nope, not using `__unused`. I did find a workaround though. Check my answer.

Comment: ok. I see. well that's what happened to me, so I wanted to share if it will help anyone.